# How to make if statement true every four loops in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, nested

I am not sure on how to ask this question, i have searched but no results. Please help.

How can I make an if statement which will repeat itself every four times insede a for loop:

```
for x in range(0,20):
     print x
     if x >= 3:
         print ","
```

As you can see here, I want the comma to repeat every four numbers and instead, I get this:

```
0
1
2
3
,
4
,
5
,
6
,
7
,
8
,
9
,
10
,
11
.
. 
.
```

Since the numbers ahead of 3 are greater than 3.
I am on python. Please help me.

Comment: "As you can see" the code does exactly what you are telling it: printing the comma if `x` is equal to or larger than 3.  You need to articulate a condition which captures the actual requirement, to print when the next `x` is evenly divisible by 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your if statement `if x >= 3` to `if (x + 1) % 4 == 0`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the modulo operator

```
for x in range(0,20):
     print(x)
     if (x + 1) % 4 == 0:
         print(",")
```

Comment: `0 % 4 == 0` , Please check this condition also,

Comment: I edited my answer. I could not really make sense out of the second part of the question...

Comment: You might want to explain the `and x` part.

Comment: x has the start value of int 0. x = 0

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to already proposed solutions, you can use two nested loops.  Have one iterate in steps of 4, and the other iterate within those steps.

```
for j in range(0, 20, 4):
    for i in range(0, 4):
        print(i+j)
    print(",")
```